# VScode delayed output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, delay, vscode-code-runner

The word "delayed" didnt really exactly describe what my situation bumped up with. I was starting practicing with C++, and using Terminal along with Code-runnder extension as the compiler. The beginning program was just that simple:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The terminal outputs the string "hello" as expected. However, when I decided to tweak the string (ex like "hellloo" or something like that). It took me 2 to 3 times to rerun/compile the program to give out the expected output. It means that whenever I apply some change in my code, it may take times recompiling to adopt that change.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you try saving your code first ? BTW you are supposed to include <cstdio> when using printf()

Comment: @TanishqBanyal I have turned on Autosave for that, and yeh I had also included <cstdio>  in the code (forgot to put it in here, thank you for reminding). The issue was nevertheless the same, still got to recompile 2 3 times to adopt new changes

Answer (score 0):

Always when using printf you should "flush" the output.
Easiest way to do that is to add \n to the printf.

> printf("hello\n");

I hope that is the solution to the problem you are experiencing.